# WPF Extended Toolkit DateTimePicker Dates validation

Tags: wpf, validation, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a scenario I can't figure out how to implement.

I want to validate that from date is less than the to date in my MVVM based WPF application. I am using the DateTimePicker control .

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,2,5,2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="From Date: "  />
                                    <xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="FromDatePicker"    
                                         AutoCloseCalendar="True"
                                         Width="200"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Value="{Binding FromDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Format="Custom"
                                         FormatString="dd-MMM-yy HH:mm"
                                         TimeFormat="Custom"
                                         TimeFormatString="HH:mm" 
                                         ToolTip="From Date">
                                    </xctk:DateTimePicker>

                                    <TextBlock Text="To Date: " />

                                    <xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="ToDatePicker" 
                                         AutoCloseCalendar="True"
                                         Width="200"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                         Value="{Binding ToDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Format="Custom"
                                         FormatString="dd-MMM-yy HH:mm"
                                         TimeFormat="Custom"
                                         TimeFormatString="HH:mm" TimeWatermark="Please select time"
                                         ToolTip="To Date"/>
                                </StackPanel>
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to validate that the to date is greater than the from date?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to perform your validation. You can do it via the bound property setters that change when the value in the DateTimePicker controls value's change. Or if you have a button that is wired up to a Command binding in your model you can do the validation there as well...

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the XAML instead of viewmodel?

Comment: You could. Wire both your DateTimePicker controls ValueChanged events and do your validation.